# cambiar un triggers de SQL a Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

Este trigger lo cree en `SQL` y me funciona muy bien, pero no tengo idea sobre como debo hacerlo en `Mysql`.

```
create trigger InsertarUsuario 
on comentarios 
after insert 
as 
    update comentarios set id_usuario=(SELECT MAX(id_usuario)FROM usuarios) 
        where id_comentario=(SELECT id_comentario from inserted)
```

Comment: Cuando dices *"lo cree en SQL"*, te refieres al gestor de bases de datos de Microsoft, SQL Server? SQL es un lenguaje. De igual manera, en [este enlace](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/triggers.html) encontrarás lo que buscas.

Comment: Además de lo que te han comentado, sobre la documentación apropiada, el trigger puede que no funcione tan bien como piensas. Si funciona, si insertas un registro, pero si insertas varios registros en la misma sentencia, no funcionará adecuadamente. Los motores `SQL` tienen que tratar conjuntos de datos, y no filas individuales. `Insert into comentarios(comentario)values('a'),('b'),('c');`, te pondrá el `id_usuario` en uno de los 3 comentarios.

Comment: Entonces la sentencia del trigger en SQL como seria con varios datos?? porque mi trigger lo que hace es actualizar el id de usuario, despues de que se ha insertado un comentario.